# Binding to DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a button template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateTest">
    <Button Margin="10" BorderThickness="2" Content="{Binding Text}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I want to create a textbox and a button whose content is the same as the textbox's text.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Margin="10">TextBox</TextBox>
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TextBox}"
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TemplateTest}" />
```

But I don't get anything on the button in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DanPuzey's one still did not work for me in VS2012. Not sure why it did in Kaxaml

This did:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox"
          Margin="10"
          Text="Hello World" />
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=TextBox,
                                  Path=.}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateTest}" />
```

and

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateTest">
  <Button Height="100"
          Margin="10"
          BorderThickness="2"
          Content="{Binding Text}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Nope soz. I don't use VS2010

Answer (score 1):

This is failing, quite simply, because you aren't setting the *content* of your content control: setting the `DataContext` doesn't change anything.  Try this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=TextBox}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TemplateTest}" />
```

The above worked for me in Kaxaml, but if it's not working for you then I'd suggest you try this instead, which explicitly binds to the text of the textbox:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextBox}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TemplateTest}" />
```

Comment: I get this error: The property 'Content' cannot be data bound to a visual element.

Comment: It worked in Kaxaml for me too, but not in VS 2012. But I still had problem with binding a string, I could only bind its Length to the button, because I didn't know I can write only '{Binding}' too.

Answer (score 1):

first you should set the content of your contentControl to be binded to the text

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Margin="10">TextBox</TextBox>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=TextBox,Path=Text}"
ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TemplateTest}" />
```

now you need change the binding of the button:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateTest">
<Button Margin="10" BorderThickness="2" Content="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: or you have the option of binding the entire TextBox as the Content of the ContentControl as an alternative and that way you can just set the Button's Content as "{Binding Text}" as the OP had. You can probably reference a bit more than just text value this way if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if `{Binding ElementName=TextBox}` sets the default `Binding.Path`.
You might try setting the `Path` to `.` : `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TextBox, Path=.}"`

Or you can bind directly the `Text` property of your element:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Margin="10">TextBox</TextBox>
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextBox}"
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TemplateTest}" />
```

and

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateTest">
    <Button Margin="10" BorderThickness="2" Content="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```